# Element shows and then hides Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm using following event and trying to hide a button if the order no is not equal to -1

```
 $('#ordPage1').live('pageshow',function(event){
            //$('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();    
            //alert(sessionStorage.OrderNo);
            if(sessionStorage.OrderNo!= -1){
                $('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();
                //alert("test");
            }
            else{
                $('#btnRegisterVisit').show();
            }
    });
```

But my problem is when the page loaded, the button shows up then vanishes instantly. Is there a way to not showing the button at all. Button shows up on the UI and then vanishes can cause problem as user might click it.

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried **pageinit** event instead? Maybe a little more code cpuld be useful.

Comment: I tried pageinit and it has the same effect. PageCreate doesn't fire the event.

Comment: I created a sample based on the code you pasted and it seems to be working fine.Here is the link-http://jsfiddle.net/wGL3b/  .So something else might be the reason.Please post some additional code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just put `#btnRegisterVisit { display: none; }` in your CSS file?

Comment: Nope dat didn't work. instead it makes the button looks weird without background only text with outline.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pageinit instead

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    if(sessionStorage.OrderNo!= -1){
           $('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();
            //alert("test");
     }
     else{
           $('#btnRegisterVisit').show();
     }
 });
```

from http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

> Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

If you've tried `pageinit` and it doesn't work.  You can also try using the `pagebeforeshow`

```
$('#ordPage1').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
        //$('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();    
        //alert(sessionStorage.OrderNo);
        if(sessionStorage.OrderNo != -1){
            $('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();
            //alert("test");
        }
        else{
            $('#btnRegisterVisit').show();
        }
});
```

> pagebeforeshow -
> Triggered on the "toPage" we are transitioning to, before the actual transition animation is kicked off. Callbacks for this event will receive a data object as their 2nd arg.

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, what I ended up doing was binding my hide events to pagebeforeshow.  In fact the events were *already* bound to pagebeforeshow, but in order to kill the 'flicker' what I had to do was move the hide events to the *top* of these methods.  Apparently other code executed before these calls can be enough to delay the calls just enough to display the buttons for a fraction of a second.  I can't say it'll work for everyone, but try this if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  span { background:#def3ca; padding:3px; float:left; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="hidr">Hide</button>
  <button id="showr">Show</button>
  <div>

    <span>Once</span> <span>upon</span> <span>a</span> 
    <span>time</span> <span>there</span> <span>were</span> 
    <span>three</span> <span>programmers...</span>

  </div>
<script>
    $("#hidr").click(function () {
      $("span:last-child").hide("fast", function () {
        // use callee so don't have to name the function
        $(this).prev().hide("fast", arguments.callee); 
      });
    });
    $("#showr").click(function () {
      $("span").show(2000);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this :

> Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()

Found on the jQuery Mobile doc

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to pagebeforeshow event.

```
 $('#ordPage1').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
        //$('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();    
        //alert(sessionStorage.OrderNo);
        if(sessionStorage.OrderNo!= -1){
            $('#btnRegisterVisit').hide();
            //alert("test");
        }
        else{
            $('#btnRegisterVisit').show();
        }
});
```